# Given the traditional ACM copyright license, is it legal to publish the paper on ResearchGate?

Tags: license, acm

The ACM license states

> (iii) Post the Accepted Version of the Work on (1) the Author's home
>   page, (2) the Owner's institutional repository, (3) any repository
>   legally mandated by an agency funding the research on which the Work
>   is based, and (4) any non-commercial repository or aggregation that
>   does not duplicate ACM tables of contents, i.e., whose patterns of
>   links do not substantially duplicate an ACM-copyrighted volume or
>   issue. Non-commercial repositories are here understood as repositories
>   owned by non-profit organizations that do not charge a fee for
>   accessing deposited articles and that do not sell advertising or
>   otherwise profit from serving articles.

Does this (somehow) include ResearchGate?

Comment: Which of the four groups do you imagine ResearchGate would come under?

Comment: Maybe (1) the Author's home page or (4) non-commercial repository

Comment: Just **don't use researchgate**. They are spammers, and it's just students there, no experts. Upload it on your homepage / institutional repository, and Google Scholar will find it. You don't need researchgate.

Answer (score 13):

**No.** Researchgate is a for-profit organization that makes money from ads and job adverts. See for instance http://osc.universityofcalifornia.edu/2015/12/a-social-networking-site-is-not-an-open-access-repository/.

Also, if you share your paper there, the Researchgate [TOS](https://www.researchgate.net/application.TermsAndConditions.html) state that you, not them, have to cover all the legal costs in case they get sued (Article 3, comma 5).