# Can I post my article publicly on researchgate?

Tags: journals, publishers, springer

My article which was just published in the subscription model by a Springer journal, yet it was made freely available by the publisher in the journal website. However, on Researchgate, no public file was added by the publisher.

Can I add the public file on Researchgate to increase the visibility of my research, since it is already being made available for free on the website? or would that be a violation of the terms imposed by the publisher for the subscription model?

Comment: It is likely that Springer has the copyright, so you can no longer freely publish it without permission.

Comment: You can ask an editor or just carefully read the license that you have from Springer. I'm doubtful, though, given ResearchGate's reputation.

Comment: It depends on copyright (as Buffy said), but also on licensing. If it's open access (not necessarily on your own merits, see Project DEAL), then you can publish it. If not, there are often some embargo time frames. For a concrete answer we'd need your country, journal name and year of publication. A general answer would be too vague and unclear.

Comment: Likely duplicate of: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/52488/75368

Comment: @Buffy and given Springer's reputation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your article isn't open access, then the answer is **probably not**.

See Springer [sharing policies](https://www.springerpub.com/journal-article-sharing-policies). You *can* share an accepted manuscript via non-commercial hosting platforms after 12 months. You can't share a published manuscript (note there is a difference between a published manuscript and an accepted one).

Note that just because the article is free right now does not mean it will be free forever. This changes if your article is open access, in which case it will be free forever, and you are free to share it wherever you want (there can be open access articles in subscription journals).

You are free to share the preprint on Researchgate, though, if you still have it.

Comment: Being "freely available" doesn't imply that it isn't under copyright.

Comment: There's a more recent edition of Springer's self-archiving policy [here](https://www.springernature.com/gp/open-research/policies/journal-policies), but the gist is the same.