# Is there a clear etiquette on providing full text paper when you are a coauthor?

Tags: etiquette, authorship, research-dissemination

As a coauthor, I occasionally receive requests for full-text pdfs of research I have worked on in the past (vis Researchgate for instance). Thus far I have generally ignored those requests - leaving it up to the first or corresponding author to reply.

However, when these requests lay dormant for a while I would like to know what the etiquette would be for providing the full text as a **middle** author?

Advantages:

- Share my work more widely, also increases visibility for the first author/senior author.
- Coauthors may have drifted away from academia, or not be on the platform.

Disadvantages:

- Not sure of the interface on Researchgate - but if they have explicitly ignored the request and then I accept it I have acted against their interest.

Comment: Make sure you read the fine print about whether you are allowed to share the paper, before uploading it on Researchgate.

Comment: I do not know whether things have changed, but be aware that ResearchGate has a history of sending fake requests on behalf of third persons.

Comment: In this situation, I share papers privately on Research gate rather than posting them publicly. Also, @Wrzlprmft makes a good point with good reason (ResearchGate earned a spam-y reputation early on). However, most if not all of my interactions seem to real people doing real interactions (or, at least RG is good enough at faking it I cannot tell the difference!).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Is there documentation somewhere about these fake requests?

Comment: @Kimball Some anecdotal examples [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16870/68109), but it's almost certainly outdated.

Comment: @Kimball: [Wikipedia documents some of it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ResearchGate#Criticism). This may be a past thing now (after they lured enough customers); at least I haven’t heard from them in a while. But then they may just have given up on me after a certain number of mails.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's your paper, even if you are just a co-author.  I can't imagine why any of your collaborators would not want to share them.  Keeping in mind that not all journals are accessible to everyone, I see no reason not to promptly acquiesce, even if  you are not the corresponding author.

Comment: Good answer.  I would add that Researchgate is a dubious platform and I wouldn't take it as seriously as an email.